# input field edit not updating ng-model for date picker?

Tags: html, angular

I have created a date picker in Angular

```
     <div class="datepicker-wrapper">
        <label for="license_expiry_date">Start Date (YYYY-MM-DD)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="fromDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'" placeholder="Enter start date" (focus)="onPurchaseDateFocus('from')" name="start_date">
        <div [hidden]="!isFromDatepickerVisible" class="datepicker-container">
            <datepicker [(ngModel)]="fromDate" name="fromdatepicker" (selectionDone)="onDateSelectionDone('from')">
            </datepicker>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I can select a date by using date picker which will update the ng-model, the input tag above the date picker is editable. but when I edit the date from the input field instead of date picker instead of selecting by date picker, ng-model is not getting updated.

Why is the value not updated when I edit the input field?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going wrong but my first guess is the one-way data binding on the form control.

`[ngModel]="fromDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'"`

try to change it to

`[(ngModel)]="fromDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'"`

More on two-way data binding

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way